# How to make Price calculations in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an add to cart page ,where display all items added to the cart.Also provided an option to edit the quantity of each product.While editing the quantity rate should change.But the fractional part is not displaying. following code is used to update value in controller:

```
public ActionResult udateCart(int id, int preview, int Qty)
        {
            float totalValue = 0.00F;
            using (APM context = new APM())
            {
                var stud = (from s in context.T_OrderDetails
                            where s.ID == id
                            select s).FirstOrDefault();
                stud.IsPreviewRequired = preview;
                context.SaveChanges();
                List<Cart> lstcarts = (List<Cart>)Session["Cart"];
                if (Session["Cart"] != null)
                {
                    var totalvalue = lstcarts.Where(x=>x.ID == id).Select(x => x.Amount).FirstOrDefault();
                    var quantity = lstcarts.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(x => x.Quantity).FirstOrDefault();
                    var total = totalvalue / quantity;
                    totalValue = Qty * total;
                    lstcarts.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToList().ForEach(s => { s.Preview = preview; s.Amount = totalValue; s.Quantity = Qty; });
                    Session["Cart"] = lstcarts;
                }

            }
 return Json(new { success = true, Preview = preview, Amount = totalValue });
        }
```

Here Amount will return a float value.But at Ajax success it received as :

```
 Object { success=true,  Preview=0,  Amount=100 } //eg:100 instead of 100.0
```

Then actual calculations carried out in ajax success:

```
 $('.eachitem').on('click', '#updateCart', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var tis = $(this);
        var itemid = $(this).data('assigned-id');
        var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty').val();
        var chek = $(this).closest('tr').find('#preview:checked').length > 0;
        var prev = 0;


    **var amt = ParseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.amont').text()).toFixed(2);**
    console.log(amt);

    **var totalb = parseFloat($('.amountclass').text()).toFixed(2);**

    console.log(totalb);


    if (chek == true) {
        prev = 1;
    }
    //var val = $(this).closest('#qtyid').find('#qty').val();
   // var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#preview:checked').length > 0;


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + '/AddtoCart/udateCart',
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id: itemid, preview: prev,Qty:val },

        dataType: 'json', encode: true,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

            console.log(data);
            $('.amountclass').remove();
           // $(tis).closest('tr').find('.amont').remove();
            $(tis).closest('tr').find('.amont').html(data["Amount"]);

            var total = ((data["Amount"] + totalb) - amt);
            //console.log(data["Amount"] + totalb);

            console.log((data["Amount"]).toFixed(2));
            var newspan = $('<span class="amont">').text(data["Amount"]);

            $('<span class="amountclass">').text(total).appendTo('.total b');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);

            if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
                alert("oooppss");
            }
            else { alert("something went wrong"); }
        }
    });



    });
```

Finally the out put is not correct,It will becomes as below :

[image]

Comment: What are the types of `totalvalue` and `quantity` (the name `quantity` suggests its an `int`, not a `float` or `decimal` (stop using `var`!) And in the script you should be converting the values to numbers before adding them

Comment: See my answer about [BigNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35312829/593958)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with monetary values, JavaScript is your enemy.

There are few libraries that solve this issue and one of them is [BigNumber](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/).
I had issues calculating hundreds of invoice details and sometimes just few of them, so I added this library to make sure my calculations are always correct. This library is based on Java's BigDecimal.

Example of additions:

```
0.1 + 0.2                       // 0.30000000000000004
x = new BigNumber(0.1)
y = x.plus(0.2)                 // '0.3'
BigNumber(0.7).plus(x).plus(y)  // '1'
x.plus('0.1', 8)                // '0.225'
```

Example to your solution:

```
var amt = new BigNumber($(this).closest('tr').find('.amont').text());
var totalb = new BigNumber($('.amountclass').text());
var receivedAmt = new BigNumber(data["Amount"]);
var total = receivedAmt.plus(totalb).minus(amt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here `ParseFloat` you can see the uppercase `P` which should be lowercase `p` because the method is `parseFloat()`:

```
var amt = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.amont').text()).toFixed(2);
//        ^-------P should be lowercase p
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating string rather than mathematical calculation

```
var total = parseInt(data["Amount"]) + parseInt(totalb) - parseInt(amt);
```